# Convert datetime to nvarchar but keep format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I am returning either a DATETIME or the NVARCHAR = 'MULTIPLE' depending on whether or not an action has been performed more than one time.

So I am trying to store the DATETIME in its normal format '2012-10-23 13:59:47.000' but as an NVARCHAR. SQL wants to make it 'Oct 23 2012 12:40PM' How can I do this?

Right now I am doing:

```
CAST(r.Date_And_Time) AS NVARCHAR(30))
```

Comment: [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx), format number `121`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Declare @CreatedDate datetime
Select @CreatedDate='20121210'
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR,@createdDate, 21)
```

Comment: I noticed converting datetime to nvarchar converting the format to 12 format by default , but this solutions solved this issue , thank you

Answer (score 9):

Use `CONVERT`. It has format parameter.

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

CONVERT(NVARCHAR(23), r.Date_And_Time, 121)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: `select CONVERT(nvarchar(23),r.Date_And_Time,121)`