# How to convert datetime to nvarchar while keeping the same format?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-format

How do you convert a datetime with timestamp to nvarchar while dropping the microseconds and keeping the same format without using a series of concatenated datepart functions? I looked around, but solution didn't work for me. -

[Convert datetime to nvarchar but keep format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772466/convert-datetime-to-nvarchar-but-keep-format)
convert(nvarchar(20), '2012-11-22 06:50:10.000', 20) = Nov 22 2012  6:50AM

Ex.
DATETIME: 2012-11-22 06:50:10.000 -> NVARCHAR: 2012-11-22 06:50:10

Comment: Tsql's CAST/CONVERT functionality is somewhat limited.  It's usually better to defer date formatting to the UI layer of your application.  In the .Net Framework environment, for example, the .ToString() method of the DateTime object is much more robust than anything tsql natively offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for me -

```
declare @dt datetime = '2012-11-22 06:50:10.000'
select convert(varchar(20),@dt,120) -- result is 2012-11-22 06:50:10
```

And here is a SQL Fiddle showing it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9bb1/7

This -

```
convert(nvarchar(20), '2012-11-22 06:50:10.000', 20)
```

does not work because the date is just a varchar

Comment: Thank you Attila! - I was able to modify it for my purposes and works well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(20), '2012-11-22 06:50:10.000', 120)
```

Comment: Thank you, Prashant! - I chose Attila because it was closer to the final solution.